# after self released

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, ios, delegates, self

I'm using a third-party Objective-C library that makes a web request in a background thread, then returns the result by using `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:...]` which then calls a delegate method. I understand that I need to `nil` the delegate reference before releasing the delegate, but I was wondering what happens if this requesting object itself gets deallocated while the background thread is running. Will this internal `self` reference get set to `nil` so that the `-performSelectorOnMainThread:` call is harmless, or is there a potential for a crash here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand your scenario (but possibly you should include some code), the statement:

```
 [self performSelectorOnMainThread:...]
```

should be the last one to be executed in your thread (since it is the way to return the result of your thread, it is still part of the thread selector passed to `NSThread`).

If it is reasonably so, then consider that when you first detach an `NSThread`, you pass it a `target` object (your `self`) and the `NSThread` will `retain` it as long as the passed `selector` hasn't completed. This will include your `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:...]`, so, unless someone messes heavily with `releases`, there should be no chance for `self` to be deallocated before  `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:...]` is executed.

If your question was exactly what happens if someone messes with `releases`, I will give this a second thought.

Comment: That's the part I was missing (that the new thread will retain `self`). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If your object is deallocated before the method on the main thread completes, you have a memory management problem. The `performSelectorOnMainThread:…` family of methods cause the receiver to be retained until it has done its work, so the only way it could be deallocated is if you're over-releasing the object.